# Workout Gaps between several date entries

Tags: java, c#, date, calendar, logic

I am trying to create a mechanism that requires a user to enter what they have been doing for the last five years

- Date range must be covered (start date 01/08/2009 - end date 01/08/2014)
- Up to ten entries are allowed
- Overlapping is allowed
- No gaps are not allowed

Currently I order the entries by start date, verify both ranges are covered. For the gaps between the entries i compare two dates at a time, entry i and i+1 and compare the start date of the later start date with the earlier start dates end date.
I find it difficult to put it into words but i think this small diagram helps describe the problem

```
START
A   x---------------------------------------y
B   x----------y
C             x--------y
D           x-----y
E                         x----------y
F                                    x----------y
                                                End
```

Here option E would fail because its start date is after D's end date, I use a while loop to add a day to the gap for everyday the start date is after the end date, this would trigger the validation, even though those dates have been covered by entry A.I am using Java to do this but even help in text and pseudo code would be great as it is more the logic im lost with ,

If anyone could help with the gaps between dates I would be very grateful.

Comment: Just collapse all entries to a single timeline and use binary search to find gaps.  What is the resolution?  Just days?  1825 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of this is simple, but you're looking at it backwards.

For every day in the requested time period, is that day covered by one of the date entries? If you find a day that isn't covered, then there's a gap and you can stop checking and send the error back to the user - don't keep checking days unless you want to notify the user of specifics of all the gaps you identify, just "fail early" as soon as you find a day that isn't covered.

So, in pseudo-code...

```
foreach (Day d in DateRange) {
    foreach (UserDateRange u in UserDateRanges) {
        //check if the date range (u) covers the day in question (d)
        if (d > u.Start && d < u.End) {
              //we're done checking this day because it's covered by at least one range
              covered = true;
        }
    }

    if (!covered) return false;
}

return true; //because if we got this far, every day is "covered"
```

So... it loops through the days, and for each day, it checks all the date ranges. If one is found that covers the day, then you can go to the next day.

There's lots of room for optimization here. For example, when you find a date range that covers one day, you can skip to the end of that date range, you don't need to check the rest of the days in that range. FOR loops with complex conditions would work here. You know you can put whatever condition you want in there, right?

```
 for (int x = 0; covered == false; x++ ) //perfectly valid
```

Comment: Jasmine this was a great help, thank you for the detailed reply. I didn't use the exact solution but a similar idea, you were right about how I was thinking of it backwards.
Thanks
Marty

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about it... create an array that can hold a merge of all the time ranges.  Go over all the dates and put them in the list.  Check over the list for gaps.  I am sure there are better ways... but for what you are doing this would work just fine.  Of course there are bugs in the blow code... but its a great start.  Thats all in C# btw.

```
int startYear = 2000;
int endYear = 2005;

void Main()
{
    int totalDays = Convert.ToInt32((new DateTime(endYear, 12, 31) - (new DateTime(startYear, 01, 01))).TotalDays);
    bool[] days = new bool[totalDays];

    List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> times = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>() {
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2000, 01, 01), new DateTime(2000, 01, 05)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2000, 01, 08), new DateTime(2002, 06, 15)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2002, 06, 19), new DateTime(2005, 12, 26))
    };

    // Go over all blocks and add them to the days array.  This could be bit logic if you really want to save memory
    foreach(Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> block in times) {
        int startBlock = GetBlockFromDate(block.Item1);
        int endBlock = GetBlockFromDate(block.Item2);

        for(int blockIndex = startBlock; blockIndex < endBlock; blockIndex++) {
            days[blockIndex] = true;
        }
    }

    // this is the actual checking for gaps...  I chose to use a linear approach.
    for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < days.Length; dayIndex++) {
        if (!days[dayIndex]) {
            DateTime missingDate = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1).AddDays(dayIndex);
            Console.WriteLine("Missing Day: {0}", missingDate);
        }
    }
}

int GetBlockFromDate(DateTime blockDate) {
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1);
    int blockIndex = Convert.ToInt32((blockDate - startDate).TotalDays);
    return blockIndex;
}
```

Output:

```
Missing Day: 1/5/2000 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 1/6/2000 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 1/7/2000 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 6/15/2002 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 6/16/2002 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 6/17/2002 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 6/18/2002 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 12/26/2005 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 12/27/2005 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 12/28/2005 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 12/29/2005 12:00:00 AM
Missing Day: 12/30/2005 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ordered list of date ranges. 
In pseudo code seeing as you don't appear to know which language you are going to use.

```
end  = 31/12/2008
foreach(DateRange d in ranges)
{
   if d.end >= end
   {
     if d.start <= end + 1
       end = d.end
     else
       // Gap found (end + 1 to d.start - 1)
       //break , return error?
       // or if you wanted to identify the all the gaps, perhaps
       // gaps.add(new DateRange(end +1, d.start - 1))
       // end = d.end
   }
}
```

Certainly no need for adding 1 day at a time.